# The write operation timed out in lambda update-function-code

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've been trying to deploy a lambda function by using the AWS CLI. The following is the command I'm using and the zip file is ~5MB.

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name <function arn> --zip-file fileb://Lambda-Deployment.zip
```

I get the following error:

> ('Connection aborted.', timeout('The write operation timed out',))

Then, I add `--cli-connect-timeout 10000` to the above command and try it again, and this time it seems to have worked, I get the output as if it worked. I check on the functions list in the Lambda console and it shows it was last modified recently and the code size to be 5.1MB.

Now, the weird part, when I click on the function in the Lambda console, all the code has disappeared in the Function Code section. There's nothing there. I just get a blank section. I've waited close to an hour after uploading the `zip` file and nothing shows up.

I've also tried manually uploading the `zip` file in the Lambda console and I get the same issue. The code disappears.

I have other Lambda functions which have smaller zip files, ~1.5MB, and they all work fine when uploading.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

For larger packages, you need to first upload to an S3 bucket, and then update Lambda from S3. Sometimes, it can even be due to a poor internet connection while uploading. It will work if you use S3. Here are the commands you need:

Upload to S3:

```bash
aws s3 cp Lambda-Deployment.zip s3://your-bucket-name
```

Create lambda function (when it's the first time):

```bash
aws lambda create-function \
  --function-name <function name or arn> \
  --runtime <runtime> \
  --role <role arn> \
  --handler <handle> \
  --code S3Bucket=your-bucket-name,S3Key=Lambda-Deployment.zip
```

Update function code:

```bash
aws lambda update-function-code \
  --function-name <function name or arn> \
  --s3-bucket your-bucket-name \
  --s3-key Lambda-Deployment.zip
```

You may also read help for all of the above commands

```bash
aws s3 help
aws lambda create-function help
aws lambda update-function-code help
```

Answer (score 2):

You can alternatively use a tool like [AWS SAM](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/sam/) that automates the process of deploying to S3 and then uploading to Lambda along with managing serverless infrastructure, local debugging and integrations with developer tools. Alternatives include [The Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/) and [APEX](https://apex.run/).